# how can we page results from a select query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a cassandra table that has more than 2 million rows. I need to fetch my results and page them. 
how can I page my results from the select query.

I am getting rpc time out when i try to retrieve 1M rows.

Comment: Depends what you use but you should have a `limit` method

Comment: What client are you using?  CQL 3+ supports paging using an internal paging state.  All of the datastax drivers and most other clients implementing the native protocol will page based on your fetch size.

Answer (score 1):

From the cqlsh command prompt, one way to do this is by restricting your hashed partition key values, via the `token` function.  Let's say that I have a table that keeps track of ship crew members (with `crewname` as my partition key):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:presentation> SELECT crewname,token(crewname),firstname,lastname 
FROM crew;

 crewname | token(crewname)      | firstname | lastname
----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------
    Simon | -8694467316808994943 |     Simon |       Tam
    Jayne | -3415298744707363779 |     Jayne |      Cobb
     Wash |   596395343680995623 |     Hoban | Washburne
      Mal |  4016264465811926804 |   Malcolm |  Reynolds
     Zoey |  7853923060445977899 |      Zoey | Washburne
 Sheppard |  8386579365973272775 |    Derial |      Book

(6 rows)
```

If I just want to bring back the all the crew members from Jayne to Zoey (inclusive) I can run a query like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:presentation> SELECT crewname,token(crewname),firstname,lastname 
FROM crew WHERE token(crewname) >= token('Jayne') AND token(crewname) <= token('Zoey');

 crewname | token(crewname)      | firstname | lastname
----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------
    Jayne | -3415298744707363779 |     Jayne |      Cobb
     Wash |   596395343680995623 |     Hoban | Washburne
      Mal |  4016264465811926804 |   Malcolm |  Reynolds
     Zoey |  7853923060445977899 |      Zoey | Washburne

(4 rows)
```

You should be able to do something similar with your partition key values as well.

Otherwise, you could probably accomplish this using one of the drivers.  In her article [Things You Should Be Doing When Using Cassandra Drivers](https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/) DataStax's Rebecca Mills describes how to page through large result sets using `setFetchSize` (her example is below):

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("select * FROM raw_weather_data WHERE wsid= '725474:99999' AND year = 2005 AND month = 6");
stmt.setFetchSize(24);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);
Iterator<Row> iter = rs.iterator();
while (!rs.isFullyFetched()) {
   rs.fetchMoreResults();
   Row row = iter.next();
   System.out.println(row);
}
```

Comment: This will only work for multi-partition range queries though won't it?  If subbu has 2 million rows in the same partition this will not work (unless I am mistaken)

Comment: @AndyTolbert That's true.  if the OP is storing many CQL rows in a partition, this will still page, but you're right that its effectiveness will be diminished.  Unless of course all 2 million rows are in the same partition, in that case it won't do anything.  And if that is the case, his performance will suffer due to hot spots.

Comment: @AndyTolbert You both are right. I think I am using cassandra for a use case that it doesnt solve.